# Mocking class constructor within method PowerMock Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, mockito, powermock

I am running into an issue attempting to mock a class using PowerMock. First off, here are my current gradle dependencies:

```
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.2'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.2'
```

I am attempting to mock calls to a kafka broker. The code looks something like this:

```
public class MyConsumer {
    public Consumer<Long, String> createConsumer() {
        ...
        Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(TOPIC);
        ....
    }
}
```

These two lines within `createConsumer` are all I am attempting to mock. My test looks something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyConsumer.class)
public class MyConsumerTest {

    @Test
    public void testCreateConsumer() {
        ...
        KafkaConsumer mockConsumer = mock(KafkaConsumer.class);
        doNothing().when(mockConsumer).subscribe(TOPIC);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(KafkaConsumer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockConsumer);

        Consumer<Long, String> result = myConsumerInstance.createConsumer();
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try to run the tests, they never begin, and I get this error:

```
> Task :compileTestJava FAILED
/Users/myuser/myproject/src/test/java/myConsumerTest.java:101: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
       PowerMockito.whenNew(KafkaConsumer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockConsumer);
                                                                 ^
Note: /Users/myuser/myproject/src/test/java/myConsumerTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/myuser/myproject/src/test/java/myConsumerTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

So I figured I would wrap the line in a try in an attempt to get more information about what went wrong. When I did so, the tests ran, but that specific test would fail giving this error:

```
Kafka.analyticsConsumerTest > testCreateConsumer FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:84
        Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException at MethodRoadie.java:87
```

I haven't figured out for the life of me how to extract any more information out of it. Has anyone encountered something like this before?

My current working theory has to do with how the KafkaConsumer class is returning a Consumer? Consumer in this instance is `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer`. Perhaps I am not mocking this correctly? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code fails to compile because `withAnyArguments()` throws a checked exception. You need to either rethrow it or add a `try catch` block.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if you reread above, I already did that. That is how I got the Runtime exception to appear. Unless I am misunderstanding what you mean? @second

Comment: If the example doesn't help you, consider adding the full stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the suggestion, but if you reread above, I already did that. That is how I got the Runtime exception to appear. Unless I am misunderstanding what you mean?

Maybe there is something missing on your end?
Check the example below, its working for me.

Gradle:

```
dependencies {

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.2'

    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.4.0'
}
```

Unit Test:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyConsumerTest.MyConsumer.class)
public class MyConsumerTest {

    private static final Collection<String> TOPIC = Arrays.asList("1");

    static class MyConsumer {

        public Consumer<Long, String> createConsumer() {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
            consumer.subscribe(TOPIC);

            return consumer;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateConsumer() throws Exception {

        KafkaConsumer<?,?> mockConsumer = PowerMockito.mock(KafkaConsumer.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mockConsumer).subscribe(TOPIC); // default behaviour, line is not required
        PowerMockito.whenNew(KafkaConsumer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockConsumer);

        MyConsumer myConsumerInstance = new MyConsumer();
        Consumer<Long, String> result = myConsumerInstance.createConsumer();

    }
}
```